# Setup docker-swarm to use specific nodes as backup?

Tags: load-balancing, docker-swarm

Is there a way to setup docker-swarm to only use specific nodes (workers or managers) as fail-over nodes? For instance if one specific worker dies (or if a service on it dies), only then it will use another node, before that happens it's as if the node wasn't in the swarm.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. However, docker-swarm does have the features to build that up. Let's say that you have 3 worker nodes in which you want to run service A. 2/3 nodes will always be available and node 3 will be the backup.

1. Add a label to the 3 nodes. E.g: runs=serviceA . This will make sure that your service only runs in those 3 nodes.
2. Make the 3rd node unable to schedule tasks by running `docker node update --availability drain <NODE-ID>`
3. Whenever you need your node back, run `docker node update --availability active <NODE-ID>`